# Fetching cookies - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, cookies

I'm doing something related to cookies in webpage. However, I need to copy the cookie fresh from the page, instead of hardcoding it (I'm new to `rails`):

```
content = "blablablablablablablabla--blublublublublu"
unescaped_content = URI.unescape(content)
# retrieve the cookie live
data, digest = unescaped_content.split('--')
session_hash = Marshal.load(::Base64.decode64(data))
```

However, given the url, for example `http://localhost:3000/login` I want to be able to read the existing cookies for a specific user id.
So let's say the `session_hash` has the following field:

```
session_hash['logged_in_id'] = 2
```

So I would like to be able to read all the cookies for that website related to that user id.

Note: Don't worry, I'm not hacking into anyones account, only testing some security settings.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller `cookies` will contain all the cookies the browser sent as part of the request. These are the only cookies you can access.